# How to show "Save password" dialog on iOS with react-native on update password page?

Tags: ios, react-native, keychain

I am using react-native and thinking how to show iOS's "Save password" dialog when users want to update their password.
For example, I see the dialog when I have forms for email/userName and password then login. Let's say we have a page after login to update the password. In this case, how do you show the one when updating the new password? Is it possible to overwrite it somehow by using built-in react-native feature - or need to install a library to handle with this? I found `react-native-keychain` and `expo-secure-store` for the similar feature.  But still is it possible to show some system modal even when there is only for forms for old/new password? I also saw textContentType prop in `TextInput` but I am not sure if it triggers it.

Comment: Set the appropriate content types (`newPassword`) on the field and iOS will handle password saving for you.  You don't need to implement any code directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your quick comment. I tried but it sometimes shows but sometimes doesn't when login. Also I am wondering if it is possible when there are only fields for password. One has "password" and I set another "newPassword" but it appeared once so far and not anymore after I tried again and again.